# C# start programs

Tags: c#

I'm create program and save with Visual studio: test.exe
Then create created program: run.exe, with code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

        Process run = new Process();

        run.StartInfo.FileName = "test.exe";

        run.Start();
```

Why this progran don't start first program(test.exe)?

Comment: Does it give you an error? e.g. "The system cannot find the file specified"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run this in Visual Studio with F5 (Debugging) or Ctrl+F5 (Without debugging) you must put `test.exe` in `your_project_name\bin\Debug` or `your_project_name\bin\Run` respectively so it can be run.

Or, you must give the exact location to test.exe when initializing process object:

```
 run.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\My projects\Test\Debug\test.exe";
```

Comment: Thanks Darin Dimitrov and Cipi

Answer (score 7):

Probably because `test.exe` is not in the same folder `run.exe`. Visual Studio by default places the compiled executable in the `bin/Debug` folder.